Default font family is getting changed in the server after upgrading from tomcat version 8.5 to 9
Recently our team has upgraded tomcat version 8.5 to 9 and we see below changes in our report generation:
In Tomcat 8.5

when we generate a pdf report from an excel file  we noticed below behaviour when we uploaded the excel file to be converted to pdf format.
Input file(Excel): Arial Font
Output file(PDF): Calibri Font

post upgrade
In Tomcat 9
Input file(Excel): Arial Font
Output File(PDF): Times New Roman
We are not supplying any font configuration, therefore we want to understand the missing configuration potentially in tomcat which causes the font to change.
We also checked the default font packages installed with tomcat are same for both the tomcat versions.
Seeking your guidance to understand on how to retain the original font which is expected to be Arial when the user uploads the file to convert it to PDF.
